# Location or Alternatives for Zends getRequest()->isPost()

Tags: zend-framework

i was wondering about where Zends functionality comes from when inside of a controller i call

$this->getRequest()->isPost()

It works, but i do not find where this "isPost()" function comes from.

I just noticed it because i don't have intellisense for that.

Question is:
Is this merely some fallback function that "newbie users" use apart from a better alternative?
Or is it perfectly valid using it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the official way to go, you can use it. Check the source code of `Zend_Controller_Request_Http::isPost()` to see what it really is doing, if you'd like :)

Comment: Or ask follow up questions if you got any :)

Comment: To explain lack of intellisense: ZF's "asbtract" request component does not have the isPost method, and the getRequest() method's codehint shows it returns the abstract request, rather than the more specific Http type, which contains the isPost method. (usually the returned object is always of the type Http, except in some less common circumstances)

Comment: Thanks Jani, this is exactly what confused me :) But i got my question solved, thanks to the both of you!